# Any way to exclude certain vertex groups from being snapped to?

Tags: vertices, vertex-groups, snapping

So I’m wanting to create an easy snapping tool where objects only snap to specific vertices on the target mesh (“connection points” if you will). I want to define these connection points but I want the target mesh and connection points to be all one object so I don’t have to do parenting. I was thinking I could do it by creating a vertex group of all the vertices I don’t want to snap to and then exclude them in the snapping options (kind of like how you can exclude non-selectable objects). Is there a way to do this in native blender, and if not, could I write a small script for this? Don’t even know if it’s technically possible. Or if there’s a better solution out there?